# DevExtreme dynamic dxSelectBox clear options issue

Tags: jquery, mvvm, knockout.js, devexpress, devextreme

I created two dxSelectBox controls with values dynamically. I perform the following steps

Step 1: Select "India" from First select box item

Step 2: Select "Mumbai" from Second select box item

**Step 3: (My Issue)** Select "USA" in First select box then i need to clear the second selectbox value but it doesn't clear the value.

On **dxSelectBox value change event**, I need to **clear** the another **dxSelectBox value**

**HTML Code (View):**

```
  <div data-bind="foreach: selectlist">
       <div data-bind="dxSelectBox: {dataSource: selectBoxDataSource, valueExpr: 'id',displayExpr:'name', onOpened:loaddatasource, valueChangeAction: processValueChange,value: selectValue, showClearButton:true }">
       </div>
  <br />
  </div>
```

**Js Code:**

js Code :

```
Application1.About = function (params) {
   var ds = [];
   ds[0] = [{ "id": "1", "name": "India" }, { "id": "2", "name": "USA" }];

   ds[1] = [
    { "id": "1", "name": "NewDelhi" },
    { "id": "2", "name": "Mumbai" },
    { "id": "3", "name": "California" },
    { "id": "4", "name": "Washington DC" }
   ];


  function selectViewModel(dataSource) {
    console.log(dataSource);
    this.selectBoxDataSource = ko.observableArray('');
    this.selectValue = ko.observable();
    this.loaddatasource = function (e) {
        this.selectBoxDataSource(dataSource);
    };
    this.processValueChange = function (e) {
        viewModel.selectlist()[1].selectValue("");
    }
  }

  var viewModel = {
    selectlist: ko.observableArray(),
    viewShown: function () {
        this.selectlist.push(new selectViewModel(ds[0]));
        this.selectlist.push(new selectViewModel(ds[1]));
    }
  };
   return viewModel;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in DevExtreme 14.1 and 14.2.3 with clearing value of dxSelectBox.

See https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T183377

It's fixed in upcoming 14.2.4. For now you can download the hotfix available there.